# Is hosting the back end in the cloud supposed to significantly slow performance?

Tags: ms-access

I moved my back-end from a local .accdb source to Microsoft's online Access App. Ever since then, forms have been taking more than 20 times longer to load. Is this normal? Or is there something wrong with my connection?

I'm using Access 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the backend is sitting on an external server, your network speed now plays a major part in the connection. Accessing local files off harddisk is fast, but accessing it of an internet connection is slower.

Try testing your app using a faster internet connection and see if there are differences. If there are minimal differences, then it could be the server hosting your app that is slowing it down. But my main bet will be the internet.

Comment: My download speed is 16 Mbps (upload is 32 Mbps), Which seems normal I think... I shouldn't have to change anything in my VBA code, queries, etc. right? Since the only difference is that the table data is retrieved from a different location, but the table names and stuff are the same.

Comment: Your local harddisk (if you are using SATA 3.0) will be 6Gb/s. Compared to that, the 16Mb/s you have is chicken feet.

Comment: Of if you are using a network share, I believe your network speed should at least be a 100base/T? That will equate to 100Mb/s. Even if we take away stuff like network lag and other bandwidth hogging issues, it should still get you more the 16Mb/s.